# How to set tab layout showing only one centered tab label

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-tablayout

This is how my app looks like: [image]

And here is my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabIndicator="@color/colorAccent"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabMinWidth="0dp"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    >
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

i've try to change the tabGravity and tab max/minWidth but nothing change

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: A) why use a screen shot that contains so much white space? B) better describe the column names, and which one work, and which one not.